# Run docker-in-docker on Openshift?

Tags: docker, openshift

As per title, Is there a way to run a Docker-In-Docker on Openshift?

There is this container: https://hub.docker.com/r/jpetazzo/dind/, but requires the privileged flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried, but it should be possible to run privileged containers inside an Openshift cluster:

https://docs.okd.io/3.9/admin_guide/manage_scc.html